# jQuery: select all links other than this one

Tags: jquery, select, hyperlink, click

I have an unordered list with five list items, each with a link inside of it:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, whenever I click on any one of these links, I want to select all of the *other* ones and then do something to them (apply a class, etc.).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `not` method to remove an element from a jQuery object:

```
$(function(){

  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('ul li a').not(this).addClass('other');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 10):

Inside the click callback:

```
var others = $(this).closest('ul').find('a').not(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select all the links, then use `.not(this)` to accomplish what you want, like this:

```
 $("a").click( function(){ 
    $("a").not(this).css("color","red");
 });
```